# Overlaying images in browser to create average image

Tags: css, image, opacity

I've been messing around recently with "average images" in which a bunch of similar images are averaged, pixel by corresponding pixel. Here's the average photo of the New York delegate to congress, for example:

[image]

(Sort of creepy, I know.)

I was hoping to make an interactive version of this online that allows people to split the image into composite parts and play around with different combinations. So as an experiment, I loaded all 24 images on top of one another (using a big sprite) and gave each one an opacity of 0.041666, just to see the effect:

[image]

This is when I realized that I don't understand how overlaid opacities work in CSS. This is a similar image but much lighter. Furthermore, **it's order dependent.** This is what happens if I duplicate the effort by reverse the order of the images on the DOM (original on left, reversed version on right):

[image]

[Live version on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2a1crc4/4/)

It's a subtle difference, but it's there, particularly in the slope of the shoulder on the lower right.

My question is whether there's any way to achieve a truly average photo in the browser by overlaying transparent images. One idea I had was to give the lower images a darker opacity so that they could compete with those images higher in the stack, but the math approach of that will depend on how the browser handles this. Code for the live version below:

```
function load_photos(sprite, parent, reversed) {
    if (reversed) {
        sprite.images = sprite.images.reverse();
    }

    var opacity = 1 / sprite.images.length;

    sprite.images.forEach(function(image, i) {
        $("<img />", { 
            alt: ""
        })
        .addClass("mugshot combined")
        .css({
            width: image.width + "px", 
            height: image.height + "px",
            background: "url('http://mechanicalscribe.com/img/demo/ny_sprite.jpg') " + image.positionX + "px " + image.positionY + "px",
            //opacity: unit * (1 + sprite.images.length - p)
            opacity: opacity
        }).appendTo(parent);
    });
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at `mix-blend-mode`. By using blending we eliminate the effects of stacking order, as the order of the images do not really matter: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/s2a1crc4/5/

Comment: Thanks. That would be perfect if it had more browser coverage, but looks very limited right now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: It is indeed a specification that is still in the works, definitely. You might want to fallback to HTML canvas for now: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/02/24/using-blend-modes-in-html-canvas/